# For loop returns multiple true statements how to return as one true bool var

Tags: c++, return, boolean

I have a for loop that goes through a vector of integers to find a specific ones digit(6) and a tens digit(1 or 2). And if it is true for ALL integers of the vector I should return true and if just one is false I should return false and print the element that makes it false.

In this case the integers in the vector satisfy the condition. But I don't know how to compile the three true's into one returnable true

```
//    ∀x∈D,if the ones digit of x is 6, then the tens digit is 1 or 2.
// vector contains [-48, -14, -8, 0, 1, 3, 16, 23, 26, 32, 36]

void question5 (std::vector<int> x){

    int num;
    int digit1;
    int digit2;

    for (int i=0; i <x.size();i++){
        num = x.at(i); //stores the integer from the vector at position i
        digit1 = num % 10; // the ones digit is stored into digit1

        if (digit1 == 6){ // checks to see if the ones digit is 6
            digit2 = num/10; // if true gets the tens digit in num
            if ((digit1 ==6 && (digit2 == 1||2)))
                std::cout << "True"<< std:: endl;
            else
                std::cout << "False"<< std::endl;
        }

    }  
}
```

Comment: [std::all_of()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) would be useful here, instead of a loop. Have you learned about standard algorithms or how to use lambdas yet?

Comment: Thank you for posting a question.  Please include a main() function and provide a [Compilable, Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  This helps us help you.  If you can make your problem as simple as possible while still creating the failure, it will help us isolate the issues that will make your code work correctly.  By providing a main() function, it saves time for the person trying to duplicate your error and help you.

Comment: You don't actually return any true statements. You just output the string "True". Why not just one bool variable starts false and once you set it true, break the loop. If that is too hard, a counter of how many conditions matched. If that is > 0 then print "True".

Answer (score 0):

> But I don't know how to compile the three true's into one returnable true

1. Change the return type of the function to `bool`.
2. Return `false` on first sign.
3. If you never encounter the `false` condition, return `true` at the end.
4. Make sure the conditional is used properly. `digit2 == 1||2` is not correct.

```
for (int i=0; i <x.size();i++){
    num = x.at(i); //stores the integer from the vector at position i
    digit1 = num % 10; // the ones digit is stored into digit1

    if (digit1 == 6){ // checks to see if the ones digit is 6
        digit2 = num/10; // if true gets the tens digit in num

        // No need for digit == 6 again. It's already been tested.
        // The correct way to test whether digit2 is 1 or 2.
        if ( (digit2 == 1) || (digit2 == 2) )
        {
            std::cout << "True"<< std:: endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "False"<< std::endl;
            return false;
        }
    }
}  

return true;
```

A simpler test would be to compute `num % 100` and test the resultant against `16` and `26`.

```
for (int i=0; i <x.size();i++){
    num = x.at(i);
    int num2 = num % 100;
    if ( num2 == 16 || num2 == 26 )
    {
        std::cout << "True"<< std:: endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "False"<< std::endl;
        return false;
    }
}

return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Compiling the three conditions into one statement can be done with three conditions joined by "and" or "&&".  If all three conditions occur, the system fails, as shown below.  After the entire vector has been checked without a problem, then you have a success situation.

I think there is ambiguity in the question about negative numbers. As written, I believe that -36, as the first number, would fail the test, but only if you take care of the negative sign:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

//    ∀x∈D,if the ones digit of x is 6, then the tens digit is 1 or 2.
// vector contains [-48, -14, -8, 0, 1, 3, 16, 23, 26, 32, 36]

void question5(std::vector<int> x)
{
  int i = 1;
  for (auto &number: x) {
    int abs_number = abs(number);
    if (abs(abs_number) % 10 == 6 and (abs_number / 10 != 1 and abs_number / 10 != 2)) {
      std::cout << "Element #" << i << " with a value of " << number
                << " is the first failing element." << std::endl;
      return;
    }
    i++;
  }
  std::cout << "All elements satisfy the criteria." << std::endl;
  return;
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> vect{-48, -14, -8, 0, 1, 3, 16, 23, 26, 32, 36};

  question5(vect);
  return 0;
}
```